# How do you browse to `[]=` in Pry?

Tags: ruby, pry

In Pry, I cannot do this:

```
>cd []=
```

or

```
>cd []\=
```

for browsing the `[]=` method for a class. Any ideas, or does Pry not work for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pry's `cd` is for objects. `[]=` is not an object. You cannot do that.

Comment: I see your point, thanks, new to Pry and fairly new to Ruby and Rails. I had cd'd into a session object and then tried to cd into that method. I did notice that `cd []` worked. Since both `[]` and `[]='` are methods, `cd []` should not have worked. Wonder what's going on.

Comment: `[]` **is** an object; it is an empty array. It is not a method in that case.